# How to handle password prompts in IBM i Pase (PHP Composer specifically)

Tags: php, composer-php, ibm-midrange, aix

I'm trying to connect to a 3rd party repository in order to include a Composer package.  I know my username and password for this repository, but I'm not entirely sure how I am supposed to submit my username and password when prompted.  I'm familiar with Unix like OS's but still relatively new to IBMi.  I understand there are some differences and I think I just may not be submitting my username and password in the correct way.

I get something like this, but after I type in my username, it just sits there for a while and then I get "Password: stty: tcgetattr: Invalid argument" and never get the prompt back ($).  In the image I use "username@gmail.com" as my username.  It never even gave me the prompt ($) for me to submit my username either (which it usually does in Unix). I just went ahead and tried typing it in to see if it works.  I even tried submitting my password right after attempting to submit my username in the same fashion.

How are interactive scripts handled in PASE on an IBMi when the user is prompted for input?  Is there a key combination I have to hit or something in order to receive control?

[image: I typically get something like this]

Comment: Does this help? http://seld.be/notes/authentication-management-in-composer

Comment: This helps me a lot.  This avoids having to provide the credentials when I run `composer update` and it works perfect for my situation and I thank you for that.  This doesn't answer the question of interacting with shell scripts in PASE.  Then again I don't know if the issue I am having is specific to Composer either.  It would be nice to know how to avoid storing credentials on disc for repositories as well.

Comment: The nature of the 5250 terminal connection used by the IBM i is such that Unix-style interaction is generally problematic. Even a simple program like `more` is completely unusable on the i. (Sure, you can use `cat` and rely on the built-in session buffer to scroll around, but my point is just to illustrate the futility of Unixy user interface conventions on this platform.) So the answer to your general question about user prompting in PASE is: In most cases, there's nothing you can do; it just won't work. (Hopefully someone more knowledgeable can respond and prove me wrong on that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 5250 session is not a TTY, so a lot of Unix applications can break if they assume they are running in a TTY. We have some custom code in OpenSSL/OpenSSH that handles this case, which makes use of the ILE APIs [Qp0zIsATerminal](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/apis/isatrml.htm) and [Qp0zSetTerminalMode](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/apis/settrmlm.htm) to do some of the things that stty is doing.

The easier solution is to just run this code from SSH, which provides a real TTY.